# How to get cloud formation template for an already deployed AWS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

If I create a resource from AWS GUI , lets say a S3 bucket or an AWS glue Job , is it possible to use AWS CLI to get the CF template for such resources. Is there any way to reverse engineer the CF templates ?

Thanks

Comment: Is not possible to use AWS CLI for Cloudformation to execute reverse engineer like do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is AWS provided [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html). But it is not maintained and in beta for years. Thus its not really useful these days, but you can try it for simple things if you want nevertheless.

There is also a new tool, called [Former2](https://former2.com/) which is up to date and generally used. But it is not developed by AWS, instead its an opensource third party solution to this problem. Since its open sourced, you can run it yourself as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no fool-proof method, the closest functionality that exists is a no longer maintained tool by AWS which is [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html).

AWS has added support to [import existing resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/) into a CloudFormation stack, however this requires that you have created the template first.